# C++ Thread Pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, threadpool, boost-thread

What is a good open source implementation of a thread pool for C++ to use in production code (something like boost)?

Please provide either your own example code or a link to example code usage.

Comment: What is the problem with boost?

Comment: @David - there is no built-in threadpool in Boost, is there?

Comment: @Steve Townsend: Right, sorry... I thought I remember one in boost, but it is not really included (has not been accepted). There is one available in http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: This FOSS project is my attempt to create a thread pool library, check it out if you want. -> https://code.google.com/p/threadpool11/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think it is still not accepted into Boost, but a good staring point:
[threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/). Some example of usage, from the web site:

```
#include "threadpool.hpp"

using namespace boost::threadpool;

// Some example tasks
void first_task()
{
  ...
}

void second_task()
{
  ...
}

void third_task()
{
  ...
}

void execute_with_threadpool()
{
  // Create a thread pool.
  pool tp(2);

  // Add some tasks to the pool.
  tp.schedule(&first_task);
  tp.schedule(&second_task);
  tp.schedule(&third_task);

  // Leave this function and wait until all tasks are finished.
}
```

The argument "2" to the pool indicates the number of threads. In this case, the destruction of `tp` waits for all threads to finish.

Comment: What is the meaning of `2` in the statement `pool tp(2);`?

Comment: @ArunSaha: Indicates the number of initial threads. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: This thread pooling library project may give some ideas. -> https://code.google.com/p/threadpool11/

Comment: @DiegoSevilla, hi, I would like to know if we could use functions that take parameters for tasks of the threadpool? thanks!

Comment: @Tianyi you may want to use a functor for that. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses

Answer (score 10):

You might want to look at http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/

It is not hard to implement [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) yourself using [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html). Depending on the task, you might want to use [lock-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) container for the queue instead of one from [Standard Template Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library). For example, `fifo` container from [`lock free`](http://www.ohloh.net/p/lockfree) library.

Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

I've written a small example [here](http://www.tonicebrian.com/posts/2012/05/23/thread-pool-in-c.html). Basically what you need to do is to implement this piece of code:

```
asio::io_service io_service;
boost::thread_group threads;
auto_ptr<asio::io_service::work> work(new asio::io_service::work(io_service)); 

// Spawn enough worker threads
int cores_number = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cores_number; ++i){
    threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
}
// Post the tasks to the io_service
for(vector<string>::iterator it=tasks.begin();it!=tasks.end();it++){
   io_service.dispatch(/* YOUR operator()() here */);
}
work.reset();
```

Comment: Don't use `auto_ptr` please! It's unsafe and its deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can emulate a thread pool with an io_service in boost::asio. You can control the number of threads available to the io_service pool, and then you can "post" tasks to the io_service, which will get executed by one of the threads in the pool. Each such task has to be a functor (I believe).

I can't put an example here right now, but the asio documentation on io_service pools will outline how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple header-only task queue using a thread pool (built on Boost): [taskqueue.hpp](https://github.com/heathkh/taskqueue/blob/master/taskqueue.hpp)

The [TaskQueue project page](https://github.com/heathkh/taskqueue) includes a sample application demonstrating [how to use it](https://github.com/heathkh/taskqueue/blob/master/test_taskqueue.cpp):

Answer (score 0):

[This library](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/index.html) builds on Boost.Thread.  There is a [short tutorial](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/tutorial/intro.html) with some example code. If this does not do what you want, you could use it as a baseline.

Make sure you are on a Boost version >= 1.37 if you go this route.

Answer (score 0):

An example implementation using the [**ffead-cpp**](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp) framework is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp/wiki/ExampleThreadPoolUsage). It provides direct, priority-based as well as a scheduled thread pool implementation. Check it out...